# How to replace black in Semantic UI masthead with color?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to replace the black color at the masthead of my webpage with an image. The following is a screenshot of what I currently have:

[image]

Basically, I'd like the black replaced with a background image. Currently, the HTML for the body is as follows:

```
<body>
    <!-- Following Menu -->
    <div class="ui large top fixed hidden menu">
        <div class="ui container">
            <div class="left menu">
                <div class="item">
                    Justin Cheung
                </div>
                <a class="active item">About Me</a>
                <a class="item">My Projects</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="placeholder" class="container">
        <div class="ui inverted vertical masthead center aligned segment">
            <div class="ui container">
                <div class="ui large secondary inverted pointing menu">
                    <div class="left menu">
                        <a class="active item">About Me</a>
                        <a class="item">My Projects</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h1>This site is under construction -__-'</h1>
    <p>
        This website is currently under construction. In the meantime, feel free to visit the 
        geese nesting within the boundaries of the University of Waterloo :)
    </p>
</body>
```

I also have the following CSS:

```
.hidden.menu {
display: none;
}

.masthead.segment {
    min-height: 700px;
    padding: 1em 0em;
}

.masthead .logo.item img {
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.masthead .ui.menu .ui.button {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.masthead h1.ui.header {
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.masthead h2 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.ui.vertical.stripe {
    padding: 8em 0em;
}

.ui.vertical.stripe h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.ui.vertical.stripe .button + h3,
.ui.vertical.stripe p + h3 {
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.ui.vertical.stripe .floated.image {
    clear: both;
}

.ui.vertical.stripe p {
    font-size: 1.33em;
}

.ui.vertical.stripe .horizontal.divider {
    margin: 3em 0em;
}

.quote.stripe.segment {
    padding: 0em;
}

.quote.stripe.segment .grid .column {
    padding-top: 5em;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}

.footer.segment {
    padding: 5em 0em;
}

.secondary.pointing.menu .toc.item {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .ui.fixed.menu {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .secondary.pointing.menu .item,
    .secondary.pointing.menu .menu {
        display: none;
    }
    .secondary.pointing.menu .toc.item {
        display: block;
    }
    .masthead.segment {
        min-height: 350px;
    }
    .masthead h1.ui.header {
        font-size: 2em;
        margin-top: 1.5em;
    }
    .masthead h2 {
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

#placeholder {
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

I've tried adding `id="placeholder"` to the container shown above, expecting that the background would be replaced with `background.jpg`; however, this has no effect. I've been stuck on this problem for several hours now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For your placeholder properties, try to use !important

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` for the `color`:

```
.masthead {
  background-color: lime !important;
}
```

Don't use `!important` for the `image`:

```
.masthead {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/JKuFTD4.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
 }
```

Comment: is there a cleaner way to do this than using `!important`?